# Анимация мерцания заднего фона

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, canvas

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать анимацию мерцания как в примере (https://emanuelemilella.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="page-header"></div>
```

Здесь `/path/to/image.jpg` - сам фон, на который накладывается зерно, а `/path/to/grainy/image.jpg` - картинка с паттерном, который будет играть роль зерна. [Пример такой картинки](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/paper-pattern.png)

CSS:

```
.page-header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("/path/to/image.jpg");
}

.page-header:after {
  animation: grain 8s steps(10) infinite;
  background-image: url("/path/to/grainy/image.jpg");
  content: "";
  height: 300%;
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  width: 300%;
}

@keyframes grain {
  0%, 100% { transform:translate(0, 0) }
  10% { transform:translate(-5%, -10%) }
  20% { transform:translate(-15%, 5%) }
  30% { transform:translate(7%, -25%) }
  40% { transform:translate(-5%, 25%) }
  50% { transform:translate(-15%, 10%) }
  60% { transform:translate(15%, 0%) }
  70% { transform:translate(0%, 15%) }
  80% { transform:translate(3%, 35%) }
  90% { transform:translate(-10%, 10%) }
}
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/animated-grainy-texture/)